# Map reverting to user's location, not allowing 'browse' iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

The map screen of the app displays the user's current location. I want to allow the user to 'browse' the map (scroll around and explore other areas) and I have a button which returns the user to the point on the map with their current location **BUT** I'm what's happening is that the app isn't allowing the user to 'browse' the map and retain the view they are looking at, rather it jumps right back to the user's current location.

Here is some code:

```
-(void) setupLocation {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        //    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
    {
        NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    }

        - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
        //    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];

        tempLat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        tempLon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tempLat, tempLon);
        MKCoordinateRegion viewRegionLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation, 100, 100);
        [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegionLocation animated:YES];

        locationNew = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        locationOld = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:oldLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:oldLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    }
```

I also have:

```
- (IBAction)stopUpdating:(id)sender {
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

And:

```
- (IBAction)findMe:(id)sender {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Any ideas of why the map keeps jumping back to the user's current location??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, in your *- (void)locationManager: didUpdateToLocation: fromLocation:*  method 
you set the region of your mapview to the updated location everytime.

### Removing this part will solve your problem.

```
  MKCoordinateRegion viewRegionLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation, 100, 100);
  [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegionLocation animated:YES];
```

**EDIT 1:**

add this line in your viewDidLoad method,

```
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

change the find me button press method like this,

```
-(IBAction) findMeButtonPressed:(id)sender;{
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegionLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([self.locationManager location].coordinate, 100, 100);
    [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegionLocation animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That DOES work, but by doing that I don't get a close-up at the user's location. what i want to do basically is when the app is launched, have the user see their current location (with the 100*100 region), allow them to roam, and when clicking the "find me" button, return to their current location. Is there a way to display the initial location as a close-up and still allow the roaming?

Comment: I don't know why, but now it isn't showing the location at all. I'm going to try it on an actual phone now and not on the simulator.

Comment: Things link location updates, better to try on a real device :)

Comment: Tried on device, still not working. It doesn't show my location on launch, <unless I'm really in London, but I don't think so> and now i'm having an access level problem on the findMe - not allowing self.locationManager - ??